# How to view whole state with react-native log-android

Tags: android, logging, react-native, redux

When I run react-native log-android, I get log messages from my react-native app. But log-messages are cut in length, I can't see the whole picture.

I output the state of my app using [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger). When my state gets really big (e.g. I have many entries in a list) log-android cuts the output and I can't see all state entries.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I use the remote debugging option to view the logs with chrome

Comment: I tried to use this method, but unfortunately it didn't work for me since I got a warning message on my device saying that "Debugger and device times have drifted by more than 60s". Even if I dismiss this warning the UI halts and there's no way I can interact with it. I tried to solve the issue with different times with the advices from similar problmes on stackoverflow, but couldn't get any luck. There's no way I can set the date on my device. It keeps returning me "date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted".

Comment: in my case debuggin option causes problems with my request. Showing me `network failed`